# UISplitViewController: How to dismiss other popovers when BarButtonItem is tapped?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I've a `UISplitViewControllerDelegate`, which is receiving the `UIBarButtonItem` and `UIPopoverController` when the UISplitViewController in rotated to landscape orientation. The following delegating method is implemented:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
     willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
          withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
       forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc
{
    barButtonItem.title = self.title;
    myViewController.splitViewBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
    myViewController.splitViewPopoverController = pc;
}
```

When *myViewController* is setting the *barButtonItem* it is placed in the *leftBarButtonItem* in the view's navigation bar.
My problem is, that myViewController has another popover, which should be dismissed, when the *leftBarButtonItem* is tapped. It is not a problem to dismiss the other popover, but the problem is, that I do not know, when the *barButtonItem* is clicked.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using the `splitViewController:popoverController:willPresentViewController:` method.

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
          popoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc
  willPresentViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController {
    [myViewController dismissPopovers];
}
```

The `dismissPopovers` method in *myViewController* is implemented to hide popovers if they are presented.

Answer (score 0):

Add your bar button item to the passThroughViews property of UIPopOverController.

```
yourPopOverController.passThroughViews = [NSArray arrayWithObject:yourBarButton];
```

This will do the trick. You can add multiple views to this array.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPopoverController/passthroughViews

Comment: Sorry, but as far as I know, the *passThroughViews* property ensure that the *UIPopOverController* wouldn't dismiss it's popover, when tapping the view specified in that property. Maybe I was not clear enough, but I need to dismiss my second popover when the *barButtonItem* provided from the *splitViewController* is tapped -- to ensure that only one popover is visible at a time.

Comment: As you want to know when the bar button is clicked. The selector for the bar button will be fired even though the pop over is visible if you add the this. I guess you can take it from there.

Comment: But which method is called by the selector for the *barButtonItem*? The button is generated by the splitViewController (as far as I know), and just handled to my in the `splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:` method.